# How to make Intellij resolve package from private maven repository in ammonite script?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, ammonite

- IDE support of ammonite works as described in this post https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2018/05/07/ammonite-support/.
- Ammonite use private maven repository also works in script as described in the link http://ammonite.io/#import$ivy

the only thing in my situation is how to let intellij find the package in my private maven repository.
intellij looks like won't consult for `~/.ammonite/predef.sc`

Comment: Hi there, I wonder if you found the way to solve the issue with intellij ? I am having the same issue i think. If the library comes from a private repo, intellij is not able to add it automatically from the Ammonite script.

Comment: my suspect is it will use `~/.m2/settings.xml`, https://maven.apache.org/settings.html but i have not try it yet.

Comment: Could you explain that better ? I can try, what do I need to change there ?

Comment: ignore the `~/.m2/settings.xml` comment, the problem really has nothing to do with it. https://get-coursier.io/docs/other-repositories

Answer (score 0):

this is the event message prompt after click the run script.

> Import all $ivy dependencies (present in local caches) declared in test.sc

so the question is what is this `local caches`, it turns out to be the coursier cache `~/.coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/` and if the package exists there, then when you click the blue import link in the event message, it can resolve it. my not so elegant solution now is sync my local cache to this repository.

the next question is how to add multiple repositories which i don't have much idea yet. (the event is from `Scala Library Extension`, not sure if it is configurable at all)

Comment: https://get-coursier.io/docs/other-repositories, there seems no straightforward way (edit a configuration file) to add a new repository...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sounds like something to explain to IntelliJ folks

Comment: BTW you mentioned : "my not so elegant solution now is sync my local cache to this repository." ?? What did you mean What is the repository vs local cache. I am not sure to follow. What i initially understood, is that you want to tell intellij to grab the data from the coursier cache but it does not know how to it ? Because the default Ammnonite cache that intellij know is not coursier.  Or maybe i am lost as to what is happening :) sorry

Comment: i mean sync all local cache to `~/.coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/`. i.e.  move the library jar to this directory, and follow the `group/package/version/lib.jar`  directory structure e.g. `com/example/functional/CI-200/functional-CI-200.jar`. basically trick intellij to think we have a local cache of the library there.

Comment: What would be the local cache directory then ?

Comment: What I have found on my side is that everything is downloaded in my courrier folder. But IntelliJ do now bring things transitively from that folder into the project. However when resolving with sbt, everything goes to ivy and IntelliJ know how to bring it to the project properly. I wonder if there would be a way to redirect courtiser to use .ivy as a cache

Comment: In short when I use the multi-stage script to add my private repository, run the script once for the resolution to happen, then IntelliJ propose to bring the libs. At that point it manage to do so, but not transitively. It only bring the top level one. When I go to coursier I can see everything is downloaded. So it is like IntelliJ does not know how to go transitively grab what is in the coursier folder (cache). However when I use sbt, I see that IntelliJ knows how to go in the ivy cache and bring everything transitively in the project.

Comment: The annoyance for me is that I can not have code assit and what not, if my object comes from libs that are a bit below in the hierarchy. Hence I need to add them as ivy imports. Each one for which I might use an object of. Otherwise the script run properly .... I hope it make sense ... anyway aside from this manual solution I don’t have one. The only one I though if, is to tell courtise to use my local ivy as a cache instead of coursier.

Comment: since i use added our nexus server to predef.sc, local cache in my context means `~/.coursier/cache/v1/https/*` other than `~/.coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2`. from `get-coursier.io/docs/other-repositories`, sync to `~/.ivy/local` might work, i never tried tho.